# what's the correct way to re-organize github repos?

Tags: github, repository

I used to put all files in one repo, recently I wanted to subdivide them into several repo with different topics. So I turned my original repo into a subfolder and added some more folders and committed. While the original repo still works, when I want to commit to the other repos via terminal, it's giving me error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The other repos still show as different repo on my github accounts.

Now when I cd into one of subfolders and do git pull, the content flow in to git_repo master folder instead of subfolder

What's the right way to re-organize repos?

Answer (score 2):

You can use git [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) :

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use
>   another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third
>   party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in
>   multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios:
>   you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be
>   able to use one from within the other.

Given the following structure, you could make `project1` & `project2` submodules :

```
project-root/
├── project1/
│   └── file_from_project1.txt
├── project2/
│   └── file_from_project2.txt
└── project-root-folder/
    └── file_from_project_root.txt
```

This could be done using :

```
cd project-root
git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo-for-project1 project1
git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo-for-project2 project2
```

Then, when you enter `project1` & `project2` folder you will be entering the git repo of these projects and will be able to `pull` & `push` from/to the Github repo.

On Github UI you will see ther submodules in your root project:

[image]